# redux-thunk not dispatching with fetch, but is with axios

Tags: redux, fetch, redux-thunk

Since nock is compatible with axios, and moxios doesn't have much documentation, I decided to use fetch. However now my actions aren't being dispatched.

```
import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from 'axios';
import { 
    CURRENT_CONDITION_SUCCESS,
    CURRENT_CONDITION_ERROR,
    LOAD, 
} from './types';

export function initializeLoad() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: LOAD, bool: true})
        fetch("http://api.wunderground.com/api/777ba6b403bf06b7/geolookup/q/autoip.json")
            .then(res => dispatch(getCurrentConditions(res.data.location.l)))
            .catch(err => dispatch({type: CURRENT_CONDITION_ERROR, error: err}));
    }
}

export function getCurrentConditions(location) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
         fetch(`http://api.wunderground.com/api/777ba6b403bf06b7/conditions/${location}.json`)
            .then(condition => dispatch({type: CURRENT_CONDITION_SUCCESS, condition: condition.data.current_observation, input: ''}))
            .then(() => {
                if(getState.isLoading) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        dispatch({type: LOAD, bool: false})
                    }, 2000)
                }
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch({type: CURRENT_CONDITION_ERROR, error: err.data}));
    }    
}
```

Any idea why?
Checking the network tab, I know I'm getting a response of 200 with all the data I'm expecting, but dispatch(getCurrentConditions) isn't getting called.

However, if I replace fetch with axios.get, everything works.

Comment: No different messages getting logged to the devtools console in the fetch() case?

Comment: None at all. The fetch call in initializeLoad is getting called, but it never dispatches the getCurrentConditions.